# onNewIntent(intent) not working as it should

Tags: android, oauth

I am building this twitter app where browser is called to authenticate from my main activity..
running the following code in a thread(AsyncTask)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

here

```
context is the context of main activity..the uri is returned through `intent`..
```

After authentication what it to do is to come back to my main activity,to its present state..
What happens now is,it create another instance of main activity..

I am using

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent); 
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("twitter", 0);
    final Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.getScheme().equals(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME)) {

        setLoggedIn(true, tlogout);
        tstatus=true;

        new RetrieveAccessTokenTask(this,consumer,provider,prefs,tstring).execute(uri);

    }
}
```

but still,the problem persist..another thing is,everything works fine in emulator(2.3)..
Not working in my device..its Android 2.3.6

my manifest is

```
<activity
    android:name=".mainActivity"

    android:launchMode="singleTask"

    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="x-oauthflow-twitter" android:host="callback" />

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: It seems the problem is for Android 2.3.5 and 2.3.6..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Twitter athentication process, but you can try `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` instead of `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`.

The later only works for you if your main activity in on top of stack, the other clears the stack and ensures that your activity in on top.

Answer (score 0):

OAuthRequestTokenTask.java

```
package com.android.twit;

import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class OAuthRequestTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

final String TAG = getClass().getName();
private Context context;
private OAuthProvider provider;
private OAuthConsumer consumer;

/**
 * 
 * We pass the OAuth consumer and provider.
 * 
 * @param context
 *            Required to be able to start the intent to launch the browser.
 * @param provider
 *            The OAuthProvider object
 * @param consumer
 *            The OAuthConsumer object
 */
public OAuthRequestTokenTask(Context context, OAuthConsumer consumer,
        OAuthProvider provider) {
    this.context = context;
    this.consumer = consumer;
    this.provider = provider;
}

/**
 * 
 * Retrieve the OAuth Request Token and present a browser to the user to
 * authorize the token.
 * 
 */
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving request token from Google servers");
        final String url = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer,
                ConstantsTwit.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
        Log.i(TAG, "Popping a browser with the authorize URL : " + url);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
                        | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error during OAUth retrieve request token", e);
    }

    return null;
}

}
```

PrepareRequestTokenActivity.java

```
package com.android.twit;

import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;


public class PrepareRequestTokenActivity extends Activity {

final String TAG = getClass().getName();

private OAuthConsumer consumer;
private OAuthProvider provider;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        // CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer
        this.consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(
                ConstantsTwit.CONSUMER_KEY, ConstantsTwit.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        // this.provider = new
        // CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(Constants.REQUEST_URL,
        // Constants.ACCESS_URL, Constants.AUTHORIZE_URL);
        this.provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(ConstantsTwit.REQUEST_URL,
                ConstantsTwit.ACCESS_URL, ConstantsTwit.AUTHORIZE_URL);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error creating consumer / provider", e);
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "Starting task to retrieve request token.");
    new OAuthRequestTokenTask(this, this.consumer, this.provider).execute();
}

/**
 * Called when the OAuthRequestTokenTask finishes (user has authorized the
 * request token). The callback URL will be intercepted here.
 */
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Log.e("", "onNewIntent() is called...");
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri != null
            && uri.getScheme().equals(ConstantsTwit.OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Callback received : " + uri);
        Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving Access Token");
        new RetrieveAccessTokenTask(this, consumer, provider, prefs)
                .execute(uri);
        finish();
    }
}

public class RetrieveAccessTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Void> {

    private Context context;
    private OAuthProvider provider;
    private OAuthConsumer consumer;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    public RetrieveAccessTokenTask(Context context, OAuthConsumer consumer,
            OAuthProvider provider, SharedPreferences prefs) {
        this.context = context;
        this.consumer = consumer;
        this.provider = provider;
        this.prefs = prefs;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the oauth_verifier, and store the oauth and
     * oauth_token_secret for future API calls.
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Uri... params) {
        final Uri uri = params[0];
        final String oauth_verifier = uri
                .getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);

        try {
            provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, oauth_verifier);

            final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, consumer.getToken());
            edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,
                    consumer.getTokenSecret());
            edit.commit();

            String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
            String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

            consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, secret);
            // context.startActivity(new Intent(context,
            // AndroidTwitterSample.class));

            executeAfterAccessTokenRetrieval();

            Log.e(TAG, "OAuth - Access Token Retrieved");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "OAuth - Access Token Retrieval Error", e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void executeAfterAccessTokenRetrieval() {
        String msg = getIntent().getExtras().getString("tweet_msg");
        String path = getIntent().getExtras().getString("imagePath");
        try {
            TwitterUtils.sendTweet(prefs, msg, path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "OAuth - Error sending to Twitter", e);
        }
    }
}

}
```

ConstantsTwit.java

```
package com.android.twit;

public class ConstantsTwit {

public static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
public static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

public static final String REQUEST_URL = "  https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
public static final String ACCESS_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
public static final String AUTHORIZE_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";

public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "x-test-oauth-twitter";
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "callback";
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME
        + "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;

}
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name="com.android.twit.PrepareRequestTokenActivity"
        android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="callback"
                android:scheme="x-test-oauth-twitter" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

TwitterUtils.java

```
package com.android.twit;

import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.http.AccessToken;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TwitterUtils {

public static Activity tmp_Add_Daily_Mood;

public static boolean isAuthenticated(SharedPreferences prefs) {

    String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
    String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

    AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token, secret);
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(ConstantsTwit.CONSUMER_KEY,
            ConstantsTwit.CONSUMER_SECRET);
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

    try {
        twitter.getAccountSettings();
        return true;
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public static void sendTweet(SharedPreferences prefs, String msg)
        throws Exception {
    String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
    String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

    AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token, secret);
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(ConstantsTwit.CONSUMER_KEY,
            ConstantsTwit.CONSUMER_SECRET);
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
    twitter.updateStatus(msg);
}


}
```

usage

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    PrepareRequestTokenActivity.class);
i.putExtra("tweet_msg", getTweetMsg());         
startActivity(i);
```

Check out this...It may help you..